# Assign random number to node in TCL script for ns-2: ERROR variable is array

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am trying to run the following tcl script but getting an error

```
can't set "val": variable is array
    while executing
"set val [random_int $upper_limit]"
```

Here is my code,Please any help

```
proc random_int { upper_limit } {
    global myrand
    set myrand [expr int(rand() * $upper_limit + 1)]
    return $myrand
}
set upper_limit 21

set val [random_int $upper_limit]

$ns at 0.6 "[$node($val) set ragent_] malicious"
```

Comment: The variable `val` is an array, but you are trying to set it against a scalar value. Change it to different variable name.

Comment: `parray val` might help with showing the current content of the array variable.

Comment: Also, mainly for preformance, [brace your expressions](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr-essions): `set myrand [expr {int(rand() * $upper_limit + 1)}]`

Answer (score 1):

Your current main problem is that there's an existing use of the `val` as an array; Tcl's variables can't simultaneously be scalars and arrays. The most expedient fix is to change the name of the variable, perhaps to `value`.

```
set value [random_int $upper_limit]
$ns at 0.6 "[$node($value) set ragent_] malicious"
```

Apart from that, your random number generator could be a bit sharper code. It probably doesn't need to access any global variables, and it really should have the expression put in braces (for a bunch of reasons including both speed and safety). Here's the trimmed/tuned version:

```
proc random_int { upper_limit } {
    expr { int(rand() * $upper_limit + 1) }
}
```

Occasionally, I write such procedures slightly differently, like this:

```
proc random_int { upper_limit } {expr {
    int(rand() * $upper_limit + 1)
}}
```

It's semantically identical, but it makes it clearer what the author is really thinking  about.